# SQL group by multiple columns with seperate where statements and left join

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause, distinct

I want to select all delivery stops for a driver. If 2 orders have the same delivery_id location it should only be one stop. Similarly if the pickup_id and delivery_id of different orders are the same it should also only be one stop. If an order has been 'Picked-up' there should be no pickup stop for it. As a seperate query afterwards I will select the orders to pick-up or deliver to the stop based on looping outcome and using the address_id.

orders table:

| order_id | pickup_id | delivery_id | driver_id | status | o_pickup | o_delivery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | Assigned | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 1 | Assigned | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 1 | Assigned | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | 1 | Picked-up | 4 | 0 |

addresses table:

| address_id | street | lat | lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 St | 40.332 | -70.332 |
| 2 | 9 Av | 40.942 | -70.942 |
| 3 | 4 St | 41.432 | -70.432 |
| 4 | 9 St | 41.321 | -70.047 |
| 5 | 0 Av | 43.031 | -72.321 |

Desired outcome:

| address_id | street | lat | lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 9 St | 41.321 | -70.047 |
| 2 | 9 Av | 40.942 | -70.942 |
| 1 | 1 St | 40.332 | -70.332 |
| 5 | 0 Av | 43.031 | -72.321 |

The following query select the correct distinct pickup_id or delivery_id and organizes in the right order however doesn't combine stop with the same pickup_id and delivery_id, how would I select distinct pickup_id and delivery_id while taking into account order status?

```
SELECT a.pickup_id as address_id, b.street, b.lat, b.lon, a.o_pickup as o_order 
FROM orders a 
LEFT JOIN addresses b ON a.pickup_id = b.address_id 
WHERE a.driver_id = 1 
AND a.status = 'Assigned' GROUP BY a.pickup_id 
UNION 
SELECT a.delivery_id as address_id, b.street, b.lat, b.lon, a.o_delivery AS o_order 
FROM orders a 
LEFT JOIN addresses b ON a.delivery_id = b.address_id 
WHERE a.driver_id = 1 
AND (a.status = 'Assigned' OR a.status = 'Picked-up') 
GROUP BY a.delivery_id 
ORDER BY o_order DESC;
```

Lastly I will have to count the to do and completed number of stops. Would I be able to achieve with a count case query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`. Otherwise your query was ok. You should only use `GROUP BY` with aggregate functions (`sum`, `min`, `max`, `count`...).

```
SELECT distinct a.pickup_id as address_id, b.street, b.lat, b.lon, a.o_pickup as o_order 
FROM orders a 
LEFT JOIN addresses b ON a.pickup_id = b.address_id 
WHERE a.driver_id = 1 
AND a.status = 'Assigned'
UNION
SELECT distinct a.delivery_id as address_id, b.street, b.lat, b.lon, a.o_delivery AS o_order 
FROM orders a 
LEFT JOIN addresses b ON a.delivery_id = b.address_id 
WHERE a.driver_id = 1 
AND (a.status = 'Assigned' OR a.status = 'Picked-up')
ORDER BY o_order DESC;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fuB5---Q).

Comment: `UNION` implies `UNION DISTINCT`.  So the de-dupping is done twice.  (Without knowing the datasets, I cannot say which `DISTINCTs` to get rid of.)

Comment: @RickJames. Not sure what you mean by that. The UNION could be UNION ALL with possible performance improvement on very large datasets, but the result would be the same.

Comment: Not a big deal [usually]...  If the results are the same, then there is a speed advantage of "ALL" over "DISTINCT".   If the two `SELECTs` might produce identical results, then `UNION DISTINCT` is needed to get rid of such dups; at this point, the SELECT DISTINCTs are redundant effort.  Etc.